# Wordpress fa-solid-900.woff2 how does it work?

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome, webfonts, google-webfonts

I am currently creating a website with Wordress. As a font, I use "Monserrat" which is a font from Google.

In the theme (oceanwp), there is the function "Deactivate Google Fonts". After I did this, the fonts were no longer loaded via `https://fonts.gstatic.com/` but locally via the `fa-solid-900.woff2` file.

Since it is important for me for data protection reasons that the font is not fetched via a connection with Google, I would like to understand how this file can contain exactly the font?

**Is this a kind of cache?**

Comment: Are you sure that the font is being loaded in the `fa-solid-900.woff2`? There is most likely no way that Monserrat is coming from that file. Do you have another plugin that loads Google fonts?